# Bootstrap popover not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am using twitter bootstrap-2.3.2 popover in my backboneJs project.

On click i am calling a function as which should trigger popover

```
<li>
 <a class="candidPopover" href="#" id="loginUser" rel="popover"><%= candidateName %></a>
</li>

myFunctionName : function(e){

 var id = e.target;

 $(id).popover('toggle', {
     animation:'true',
     placement:'bottom', 
     title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover',
     content: "It's so simple to create a tooltip for my website!"
  });
```

function is called but popover doesn't open up.

Comment: I have already added popover and tooltip bootstrap files

Comment: popover open up for the first time only , If i add animation, title parameter to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/oyOVireH/2/edit

Remove the `'toggle'` and it should work just fine.